# AngularJs / Using jquery selector in a jasmine test does not work

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Suppose a jasmine test exposing this code in the `beforeEach` block:

```
//....
element = $compile('<input class="form-control" class="email" name="email" id="email" type="email" ng-model="user.email" />')($rootScope);
$rootScope.$digest();
//.....
```

In some test, I put a simple:

```
console.log($('#email').name);
```

expecting thus the output of the value: `email`.

However, I get an `undefined`.

So my question is: Is jquery compatible by default (without [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) plugin or anything else)? Of course, in my karma configuration, jquery is loaded before angularjs.

Of course, passing by the traditional `element.find(...)` works well (although does only work with tagnames) , but I would like to use Jquery selector instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery id selector uses `document.getElementById()`. Your compiled element is not part of the DOM, which is why `console.log($('#email').name);` gives `undefined`.

If you have a single element like in your example you simple need to do this:

```
console.log(element.attr('name'));
```

And as long as you have jQuery loaded before AngularJS `find` will work with more than tag names. So if you have a nested element:

```
var nestedElement = $compile('<div><input class="form-control" class="email" name="email" id="email" type="email" ng-model="user.email" /></div>')($scope);
```

You can:

```
console.log(nestedElement.find('#email').attr('name'));
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/KRmoWRq8efvb4QhwDXAX?p=preview